# How do I destructure an object into new objects in a function using es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Here is the code:

```
const toDoList = {
    title1 : "Quiet Time",
    title2 : "Study",
    title3 : "Go Jogging",
    title4 : "Eat Breakfast",
    description1 : "",
    description2 : "",
    decription3 : "This is going to help to reach my goals and my life to the fullest",
    decription4 : "",
    date1 : "05/02/2020",
    date2 : "01/02/2020",
    date3 : "tomorrow",
    date4 : "today",
    time1 : "08:12",
    time2 : "13:15",
    time3 : "12:36",
    time4 : "13:25",
    completed1 : false,
    completed2 : true,
    completed3 : false,
    completed4 : true,
    priority1 : "red",
    priority2 : "yellow",
    priority3 : "black",
    priority4 : "white",
    tags1 : ["Personal", "Work", "School"],
    tags2 : ["Personal", "School", "Diary Entry"],
    tags3 : ["Content Creation", "Personal"],
    tags4 : ["Personal"]
  };
```

What I've done:
`const { title1, description1, date1, time1, completed1, priority1, tags1 } = toDoList;`

I haven't been able to figure out how to get passed this point and I'm unsure if the above line would even be used in the function.
Much appreciated!
EDIT:
The challenge I'm trying to solve which is the reason for this post:
It is your challenge to destructure the data which is in the form of a single object, then restructure the data into several individual objects each representing a single task datum.
This must all be done programmatically.
As an additional challenge, think about how you can use arguments to configure the behaviour of your function such that you can represent 1 or 100 (or any amount of) users without having to rewrite any of the function definition.
*EDIT2:*
I believe my end result is supposed to be 4 objects, each with their own title, description, date etc.
Similar to how this would work: `const { title1, description1, date1, time1, completed1, priority1, tags1 } = toDoList;`
however that won't be dry coding as I would have to have it so that I am able to run through the code even if there are like 100 titles each needing it's own object.

Comment: What kind of new objects you need? How are you using the new objects? Where is the function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Possibly related: [Iterating through a badly designed API where object keys consist of text and numbers](/q/49835981/4642212). If you need an array of four objects, each having a `title`, `description`, etc., destructuring won’t be of much help. Use the available [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it will serve you to offer a complete solution, but here is an example of one way of extracting a task from the `toDoList`

```js
const task1 = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(toDoList)) {
  if (key.endsWith('1')) {
    task1[key] = Array.isArray(value) ? [...value] : value;
  }
}

console.dir(task1);

/*
{ 
  completed1: false
  date1: "05/02/2020"
​  description1: ""
​  priority1: "red"
​  tags1: [ "Personal", "Work", "School" ]
​  time1: "08:12"
​  title1: "Quiet Time"
}
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is sort of what I was looking for and will allow me to continue a bit. However, would there be a way to have this as dry code where I wouldn't need to create a function for each number, such as if there were title1 - title100? 
Pseudo code: 
``` if (key.startsWith("title")){}```
then find the end value of the title and iterate through the object to find all entries that end with the same value and push them all into an object?

Comment: Yeah, this is as non-dry as it can be. It is sort of using Object.entries as I already posted but in an non dynamic way

Comment: @TrashPanda I think you should try to work it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) using an array as accumulator

I destruct the key into keyName and IDX using a regular expression

```js
const toDoList = { title1 : "Quiet Time", title2 : "Study", title3 : "Go Jogging", title4 : "Eat Breakfast", description1 : "", description2 : "", description3 : "This is going to help to reach my goals and my life to the fullest", description4 : "", date1 : "05/02/2020", date2 : "01/02/2020", date3 : "tomorrow", date4 : "today", time1 : "08:12", time2 : "13:15", time3 : "12:36", time4 : "13:25", completed1 : false, completed2 : true, completed3 : false, completed4 : true, priority1 : "red", priority2 : "yellow", priority3 : "black", priority4 : "white", tags1 : ["Personal", "Work", "School"], tags2 : ["Personal", "School", "Diary Entry"], tags3 : ["Content Creation", "Personal"], tags4 : ["Personal"] };
  
 const objects = Object.entries(toDoList).reduce((acc,[key,value]) => {
   // match returns match, group1 (key) and group2 (idx)
   const [_,keyName,idx] = key.match(/([^\d]+)(\d)/); // getting the key and idx
   if (acc.length<+idx) {
     acc.push({[keyName]:value})
   }  
   else acc[idx-1][keyName] = value
   return acc
 },[])
 console.log(objects)
```

or this, using an object as accumulator.

```js
const toDoList = { title1 : "Quiet Time", title2 : "Study", title3 : "Go Jogging", title4 : "Eat Breakfast", description1 : "", description2 : "", description3 : "This is going to help to reach my goals and my life to the fullest", description4 : "", date1 : "05/02/2020", date2 : "01/02/2020", date3 : "tomorrow", date4 : "today", time1 : "08:12", time2 : "13:15", time3 : "12:36", time4 : "13:25", completed1 : false, completed2 : true, completed3 : false, completed4 : true, priority1 : "red", priority2 : "yellow", priority3 : "black", priority4 : "white", tags1 : ["Personal", "Work", "School"], tags2 : ["Personal", "School", "Diary Entry"], tags3 : ["Content Creation", "Personal"], tags4 : ["Personal"] };
  
 const objects = Object.entries(toDoList).reduce((acc,[key,value]) => {
   const keyName = key.replace(/\d/g,"")
   acc[keyName] = acc[keyName] || []
   acc[keyName].push(value)
   return acc
 },{})
 console.log(objects)
```

Comment: I am quite new to javascript and coding in general so this seems a bit far for my understanding, is there a link you can send me to understand this stuff? Much appreciated for the response though

Answer (score 1):

This answer is similar to @mplungjan.

```js
const toDoList = { title1 : "Quiet Time", title2 : "Study", title3 : "Go Jogging", title4 : "Eat Breakfast", description1 : "", description2 : "", description3 : "This is going to help to reach my goals and my life to the fullest", description4 : "", date1 : "05/02/2020", date2 : "01/02/2020", date3 : "tomorrow", date4 : "today", time1 : "08:12", time2 : "13:15", time3 : "12:36", time4 : "13:25", completed1 : false, completed2 : true, completed3 : false, completed4 : true, priority1 : "red", priority2 : "yellow", priority3 : "black", priority4 : "white", tags1 : ["Personal", "Work", "School"], tags2 : ["Personal", "School", "Diary Entry"], tags3 : ["Content Creation", "Personal"], tags4 : ["Personal"] };

let deconstructed_objects = Object.entries(toDoList).reduce((a, b) => {
    // Splits the property name and the number index (returns an array)
    const [property, index] = b[0].match(/\D+|\d+/gi);
    
    // Assign values to an object based on the number index - 1
    a[parseInt(index)-1] = {...a[parseInt(index)-1], [property]: b[1]}
    return a 
}, []);

console.log(deconstructed_objects);
```

Comment: Similar, but harder to grasp if my answer is hard for a beginner  :) Still neater than mine. Are you truly destructuring though? it looks more like assigning except the property/index

Comment: Not really deconstructing if we look at the code. You get the idea, haha. And yup, I can agree yours is neater. ;)

Comment: I said yours were neater. I cleaned up my key/idx code inspired by yours